# ASP.net MVC Routing problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two problems;

First, I can not go to the main page URL. It is not working as it is on the login page:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


 public ActionResult Login(string email, string password)
    { 
        model = BLcontext.GetUserLogin(email, password);

        if (model.UserID > 0)
        {   
           return Redirect("/Home/Index");
           or  return PartialView("Index");
           or  return RedirectToAction("Index");            

        }          
        return PartialView("Login");
    }
```

Second, how can I get userId value?

```
clientAuth  "c495600a-71b3-44cb-a577-634426597c82,{\"UserID\":2,\"CurrentSessionID\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"},16.01.2015 15:50:53"
```

I did it

```
clientAuth.Split(',')[1]
```

but I see it.. I want value 2

```
return :"{\"UserID\":2"
```

Comment: In C# array index start from 0. Try clientAuth.Split(',')[0]                            Also what does it mean by "It is not working as it is on the login page"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure *what* or *where* your problem is based on what you've submitted.  However, it should be as easy as this:

*Home Controller: (Default Defined in your Routes)*

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

By default that is a *Get*, which will automatically be returned when you call the raw controller.

On your other page, when you have an *Event* that occurs from a user interaction, you simply declare the method and direct to proper action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateCustomer(int? id)
{
     if(id != null)
          return View("/SomeOtherController/Example");

      return View("/Home/Index");
}
```

That would take the `<form action="/Home/ValidateCustomer" method="POST">` and automatically force the submit input to pass your parameter in your fields, then go to the `ActionResult ValidateCustomer` hopefully this clarifies navigation a bit for you.